# Varchar(max) showing as text in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have two columns in my database that is running on SQL Server 2008R2(10.50.4000) that are varchar(max), but in SQL Server Management Studio (11.0.5343.0) they show as text in the Explorer window.

[image]

When I run a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    J.TICKETID, 
    J.jobNotes,
    J.jobScopeOfWork
FROM 
    sysdba.ALX_JOB J 
JOIN 
    sysdba.ALX_JOBTYPE T ON J.JOBTYPEID = T.ALX_JOBTYPEID 
JOIN 
    sysdba.ALX_JOBSTATUS S ON J.STATUSID = S.ID 
JOIN 
    sysdba.ADDRESS A ON J.ADDRESSID = A.ADDRESSID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sysdba.ALX_JOB_JOBUSERS ju ON j.TICKETID = ju.ticketId 
WHERE 
    (ju.ALX_USERID = '12345' OR j.UserID = 12345)
```

I get the error

> Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.
>
> Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

The compatibility option is set as follows

[image]

Comment: What version is the underlying SQL Server **database engine?** The version of the management GUI is rather irrelevant - it's the **engine** that defines which datatypes are there (or not). Run `SELECT @@VERSION` on your database and report back. Also check the **compatibility level** of the database (in the Object Explorer, right-click on your database > Properties > Options > Compatibility Level)

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2(10.50.4000)

Comment: And the compatibility level?? If it's set to "80" (SQL Server 2000) - you cannot use  `Varchar(max)` ......

Comment: Thats what its set to, that must be it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database **engine** is running on SQL Server 2000, or if your database **compatibility level** is set to "80" (SQL Server 2000), then that database doesn't know about `varchar(max)` yet.

Change your compatibility level to a more recent version!